# How to join two pandas dataframe such that the second table repeats

Tags: python, pandas

I have tow dataframe df1 & df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
  )
```

**`df1`**

```
    A   B   C   D
0   A0  B0  C0  D0
1   A1  B1  C1  D1
2   A2  B2  C2  D2
3   A3  B3  C3  D3
```

**`df2`**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "E": ["A4"],
        "F": ["B4"],
        "G": ["C4"],
        
    },
)
```

**`df2`**

```
       E    F   G
    0   A4  B4  C4
```

When I do a join only the first row of df2 is populated as it is single row and rest are given as NULL

```
output = df1.join(df2)

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   A0  B0  C0  D0  A4  B4  C4
1   A1  B1  C1  D1  NaN NaN NaN
2   A2  B2  C2  D2  NaN NaN NaN
3   A3  B3  C3  D3  NaN NaN NaN
```

Is there a way to join such that instead of NaN the row repeats in the rest of rows as below

**Desired Output**

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   A0  B0  C0  D0  A4  B4  C4
1   A1  B1  C1  D1  A4  B4  C4
2   A2  B2  C2  D2  A4  B4  C4
3   A3  B3  C3  D3  A4  B4  C4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is only forward filling missing values, not working if some missing values in `df1` - also replace them:

```
output = df1.join(df2).ffill()
print (output)
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  A4  B4  C4
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  A4  B4  C4
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  A4  B4  C4
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  A4  B4  C4
```

Or use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with unpack `Series` created by first column of Dataframe - disadvatage is it failed if integers columns names in `df2`:

```
output = df1.assign(**df2.iloc[0])
```

Or use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same index in both `DataFrame`s, also are repeated values by `method='ffill'` parameter:

```
output = df1.join(df2.reindex(df1.index, method='ffill'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge`, with `how = 'cross'`:

```py
 df1.merge(df2,how = 'cross')

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  A4  B4  C4
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  A4  B4  C4
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  A4  B4  C4
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  A4  B4  C4
```

If your data is fairly large, you could use [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) for more performance:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1
.expand_grid(
    df_key = 'df1', 
    others = {'df2':df2})
.droplevel(axis = 1 , level = 0)
)
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  A4  B4  C4
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  A4  B4  C4
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  A4  B4  C4
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  A4  B4  C4
```

Do keep in mind that this is a Cartesian product, so be careful about memory consumption

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from jezrael, you can also use the entire single row of df2 as an input to fillna, and it will apply to the appropriate columns:

```
output = df1.join(df2).fillna(df2.iloc[0])
```